# Как создать контейнер типа параметра?

Tags: python, list, типы-данных

Есть функция:

```
import typing

def foo(sequence: typing.Sequence):
    ...
```

Как в ней создать контейнер такого же типа, что и тип параметра? Например, если `sequence` это `list`, то создать `[]`. Без явного перебора вариантов.

Comment: В общем случае это невозможно. Тип контейнера может оказаться таким, который запрещает себя создавать кому попало

Comment: Вы конечно можете попытаться использовать что-то вроде `type(sequence)(параметры)` но нет никакой гарантии, что это будет работать для всех возможных типов

Comment: @andreymal и шо тогда делать? использовать фиксированный тип вместо `Sequence`? Мне нужна модифицированная копия `sequence` в результате, не изменяя её саму

Comment: Вот кстати [похожий вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66892519). Судя по отсутствию ответа там, подозреваю, что внятного решения не существует

Comment: @andreymal печально D: